# Overriding variables used by other variables

Tags: less

I'm having a real hard time debugging a situation with overriding variables in my Less code.  The structure is like so:

```
less
|- theme.less
|- theme-high-contrast.less
|- styles.less
|- variables.less
|- variables-high-contrast.less
```

theme.less:

```
@import('variables');
@import('styles');
```

variables.less:

```
@brand-blue: <blue>;
@brand-primary: @brand-blue;
```

theme-high-contrast.less

```
@import('variables-high-contrast');
@import('styles')
```

variables-high-contrast.less

```
@import('variables');
@brand-blue: <some other blue>;
```

styles.less

```
.foo {
  color: @brand-primary;
}
```

The two `theme` less files generate different css outputs that get swapped out based on what theme is active.  The output I get is similar to this:

theme.css and theme-high-contrast.css

```
.foo {
  color: <blue>
}
```

Both files have the same value for that variable, despite it being explicitly overridden and I can't for the life of me figure out why.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue. I.e. are you sure there's no `@brand-blue: ...` variable defined somewhere within `styles.less` or so? Either way the most typical issues usually come when people miss the [declarative semantics of variables](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2442#issuecomment-73841148) in Less.

Comment: Aside of that... It's really strange - now what does happen when you simply comment any `@import "whatever-variables";` line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at what the `less` documentations says about lazy evaluation of variables. Look at those two examples:

```
.lazy-eval {
    width: @var;
}

@var: @a;
@a: 9%;
```

And another one:

```
.lazy-eval {
    width: @var;
    @a: 9%;
}

@var: @a;
@a: 100%;
```

Both will compile to:

```
.lazy-eval {
    width: 9%;
}
```

> When defining a variable twice, the last definition of the variable is used, searching from the current scope upwards. This is similar to css itself where the last property inside a definition is used to determine the value.

So you have in your variables less file:

```
@brand-blue: <blue>;
@brand-primary: @brand-blue;
```

Later in the theme less file:

```
@brand-blue: <some other blue>;

.foo {
    color: @brand-primary;
}
```

Will compile to:

```
.foo {
    color: <blue>;
}
```

When including files, last definition of a variable will win. So the last defined value for `@brand-primary` will be used (`<blue>`).

To achieve what you are trying to do, you must change `@brand-primary` in your theme `less` files. Other approach will be not defining `@brand-blue` in `variables.less` so you can assign the value later on you theme file.

You can [read more](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature) about less variables in its official website.

Hope it helps.

Comment: *you change the value of `@brand-blue`, `@brand-primary` will still be <blue> because you already assigned it before.* - actually *you* should read the official docs as it's exactly the opposite to how you believe it would be.

Comment: @seven-phases-max like mentioned in the link i posted about the documentation, section about variables lazy load, if `@: 9%; @var: @a;` then later `@a: 100%;`, when compiled `@var` will still be 9%. So if `@brand-blue: <blue>; @brand-primary: @brand-blue;` then `@brand-blue: <green>;`, when compiled `@brand-primary` will still be <blue>. You can test the example of the question in a few simple files like i did before.

Comment: @seven-phases-max reviewing my answer to your comment and reading my post answer again, i found out your point. I got it right, but wrote it wrong in the las paragraph I edited. Thanks for making me think again :-)

Comment: Better but you still got it wrong a bit. In the lazy-evaluation example the result of the second example is `9%` not because you've assigned `9%` to `@a` *first* but because the value of `@a` within `.lazy-eval` *scope* is just that (the example is about *scope*). And your second example with `.foo` is still incorrect. [Demo](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40brand-blue%3A%20blue%3B%5Cn%40brand-primary%3A%20%40brand-blue%3B%5Cn%5Cn%40brand-blue%3A%20red%3B%5Cn%5Cn.foo%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20color%3A%20%40brand-primary%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn%22%7D).

Comment: @seven-phases-max so in my foo example, it willl compile to <some other blue>. The fact that the user from the original question is getting foo compiled to <blue> is because the scope of `@brand-primary` is the include file. Am i right?

Comment: In the original question I suspect the problem is elsewhere (it's hard to tell for sure w/o more info) - I suspect he just have another `@brand-primary` within `style.less` or so (so this latter value is used instead) but it's also possible it's just some unrelated mistake in the "switching themes" or so. But when it comes to the imports - yes, within the same scope the last definition always wins (they even have the LDW nickname for this behaviour).

Comment: @seven-phases-max great! Thanks for your help. I will update my answer to include information about the scope. Like i said before, i tested it using two files as in the original question and i got the same result. Seems like the problem is the last definition in the import. Thanks again!

Comment: Just the last remark - as it seems I did not stressed this in clear enough fashion in my prev. comment. Note the `@import` statement does not create any scope. Scope is created only by explicit `{...}` statements (and a few others in a more exotic edge-cases). But all imported files share the same (global) scope with each other (in that sense the Less `import` statement is more like "include"/"inject" and not to be confused with for example with JavaScript "import" works - that's totally different mechanics).

Comment: @seven-phases-max so in this case is not a scope issue, is that when imported the last definition of `@brand-primary` wins.

Comment: Yes, I see no scope trickery in the original question. And more strictly speaking the winner is last definition of `@brand-blue` not even `@brand-primary` (if the latter is also not redefined to point something else of course).

Comment: I did some more research into this and this was in fact what was happening, though it was for a different reason.  Short version being that on this project, bootstrap is imported in the less files as the base theme, and customized as needed in the main theme files.  Individual Angular components have their own less files, and some of those were importing bootstrap and causing weird issues with color overrides. But the crux of the issue was that I was importing the variables twice without using `(multiple)` so the second import wasn't actually happening.